# What is the HIP recording?

Tags: knowledge, rebus, music, emoji

**CAN YOU FIGURE OUT THE FAMOUS RECORDING BASED ON THESE 7 CLUES?**

[image]

[image]

Hints:

> Focus on the 3rd clue and use google, it will be the best way at progressing. Also this isn’t an [ISIS style](https://www.mit.edu/%7Edwilson/puzzles/puzzlewriting.html) puzzle (the title is short).

> For the first clue look at the song’s origins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> [Charlie Parker, Koko, 1945](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko-Ko)

Clue 1:

> NEIGH TEETH -> Native  Flag -> American.   My best guess is that the finger means one, and the French flag means translate, which is un or une.  With the musical notes and the hint in comments, I'm going with NATIVE AMERICAN TUNE -- which references "Cherokee" - The song KOKO was based on.

Clue 2:

> AABA is the great American song form -- Lines 1,2 and 4 have the same melody, and Line 3 has a different on - Sing "Happy Birthday" for an example.  KOKO follows this pattern.

Clue 3:

> This looks like "Bird Sax Roach Drums"  Charlie Parker was a sax player known as "Bird", and Max Roach was his drummer.

Clue 4:

> OK OK - Which is KOKO backwards

Clue 5:

> BEE BOP (hammer = hit and I looked for synonyms of hit) -  Sounds like Bebop, a jazz genre. Koko is an example of bebop.

Clue 6:

> ELEPHANT clues BIG + APPLE = New York City - where it was recorded

Clue 7:

> WORLD WAR(gun) TWO clues 1945, the year of the recording

Title refers to

> [Hipsterism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipster_(1940s_subculture)).

Comment: I'm hopeless on the first clue.

Comment: I'm really stretching here.  Is it ROT13(ANGVIR NZREVPNA ONAQ [Arvtu-Grrgu Nzrevpna Onaq sebz gur iregvpny onaqf ba gur Serapu synt])

Comment: And with that attempt, I give up if it's not right.

Comment: Yep fantastic well done 